# How can I remove locks on an object?

Tags: oracle-10g, locked-objects

One of my queries is running in to a Row Lock Contention. I've tracked down which table is causing that - so now what's the next step ? Which session is causing this table to get locked ? How do I remove the lock ?

I'm using Oracle 10g

Comment: Is this a one-off error? Or is this happening every time you restart the database? Can you give us more details?

Comment: @Brain it was a one-off error, and lock eventually was released since all db's have a timeout limit here, was wondering what would be the way to go for a scenario like this, without having to wait for timeouts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in `DBA_BLOCKERS` and `DBA_WAITERS`. If you don't have these views, as SYS run `@?/rdbms/admin/catblock`.

You can remove the lock by killing the session, but you will then need to wait for Oracle, specifically PMON, to roll back that session's outstanding work.